# how to push the textview down?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="30dp" >

    <
        android:id="@+id/uconnecttitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_logo_uconnect" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft = "10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#d0d0d0"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uconnecttitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft = "10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#d0d0d0"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextVersionNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#008000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/appVersionName"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UserAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:text="dfgfdgdfg"
        android:textColor="#B0171F"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PwdAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pwdfield"
        android:text="dsfsdf"
        android:textColor="#B0171F"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/troubleLoggingIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/troubleLoggingIn"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#0645AD" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to push TextVersionNum down, I tried `android:layout_marginBottom="0"` but it does not bring the item down to the bottom. How can I move TextVersionNum as close to the bottom screen as possible? I also tried to set the padding for troubleLoggingIn, `android:layout_marginBottom="0"` but I do not see anything happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextVersionNum might not be at the absolute bottom because if the container's padding:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="30dp" >
```

Try to set padding of the `relativeLayout` only for the other margins (top, left and right).

Comment: Yep this was it, as the version is already on the bottom. So adjusting this padding fixed it. Thank you.